# Create ClouldFormation stack for the specific folder in S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I tried out image resize functionality using cloud-formation service. when create the stack asked selected our s3 bucket. after creating the stack it gives cloud-front ApiEndpoint But it gave from the root directory of s3 bucket.

for the example :
s3 bucket path: https://surathbucket1.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/png.png

cloud-front path for stack: https://d1njf1ibm6jv3d.cloudfront.net/png.png

I need to create a stack for a specific folder in s3 bucket instead of the root directory.

for the example:
s3 bucket path: https://surathbucket1.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/test/png.png

cloud-front path for stack: https://d1njf1ibm6jv3d.cloudfront.net/png.png

I used this template for creating a stack
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/solutions/latest/serverless-image-handler/template.html

anyone know the answer please help me. Thank you

Comment: Your images are not working.

Comment: @marcin it works

Comment: Not here. Can you check in incognito mode?

Comment: working fine. I checked with mobile phone also

Answer (score 0):

There is no such an object type as folder in S3. There is only an object itself which is prefixed with for example test/. So, in your case, the name of your object should be test/png.png

Check docs this out: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/using-folders.html